# Button color totally transparent

Tags: c#, winforms, button, colors, transparency

So I have image in button but my problem is default color of button. I changed back color of button to color of my panel but I still have border around it, is there a way to remove it so entire button color would be transparent and only image would be visible ?

Comment: Why not just use a label?

Comment: Problem is that I already code everything and I would need to change a lot then

Comment: WinForms or WPF or ...?

Comment: you can use `Bitmap.MakeTransparent` to make certain colors in the image transparent (if that is the problem)

Comment: Its in WinForms, I need to make button color transparent not image

Comment: It's actually simple @originorigin2 You only need to attach your label_click method to your previous button click method.

Comment: It will be an overkill solution to try to remove the borders drawn by Windows for buttons.

Comment: "Problem is that I already code everything and I would need to change a lot then". If you mean that you have many WinForms buttons defined, then it is fairly easy to change them to Label controls. Despite normal recommendations that you never edit the .Designer.cs file, it is OK to do it if you're careful. Create one Label so you can see what it looks like in .Designer.cs. Stop Visual Studio. Make a backup of .Designer.cs. Load it into a text editor. Look at what needs to be done to convert the Button controls into Label controls and do it. Start Visual Studio. All done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = //Set your Background color here
```

Comment: @originorigin2 if answer helps you than you can up vote also dear.

Answer (score 0):

By default, controls do not support transparent backcolors. However, you can allow your control to have a background color that is opaque, transparent, or partially transparent by using the Control.SetStyle Method in the constructor. The SetStyle method of the Control class allows you to set particular style preferences for your controls, and can be used to enable or disable support for transparent backcolors.

To give your control a transparent backcolor

- In the Code Editor for your control, locate the constructor.
- Call the SetStyle method of your form in the constructor.

  SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

This will enable your control to support a transparent backcolor.

- Beneath the line of code you added in step 1, add the following line. This will set your control's BackColor to Transparent.

  this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

Comment: This Transparent changes color back to default color of button and then again I have color around my image which is in this button